# Kentico 13: Error while saving the document

Tags: kentico, kentico-mvc, kentico-13

I have a site in Kentico v13.0.104.

I have created a new custom page type.

When I am trying to save the custom page type within the parent folder say "Templates", the page type is getting saved successfully.

But When I am trying to save the same custom page type within a child folder named "News" inside the parent i.e. ("Templates/News") folder in Kentico content tree, I am getting the following error:

[image]

[image]

Please suggest.